# RF coil impedance matching inconsistant result

Tags: rf, coil, impedance-matching

I'm trying to do impedance matching from a signal generator (60MHz with 50ohms impedance) to a copper wire coil (6 rounds). The coil is connected by a wire (~6 meters long) with resistance 0.9 ohms.

Here is the steps I am planning:

Step 1: calculate the load impedance, both Load Resistance & Load Reactance.

Step 2: insert these values into:
http://home.sandiego.edu/~ekim/e194rfs01/jwmatcher/matcher2.html

In Step 1, I connect the coil + transmission wire in series with resistor. I'm obverving both coil voltage & resistor voltage. And because:

U(resistor) / U(coil) = R(resistor) / Impedance(coil),

I can solve the coil reactance by: Reactance(coil) = Impedance(coil), because it is a 6 rounds coil, with almost 0 resistance.

Here is my problem, I'm using different non-inductive resistors (1 ohms, 3 ohms, 5 ohms). They all give me different results of Reactance(coil).

So how can I determine the reactance of this?

Comment: I would strongly suggest doing the matching to 50 Ohm right at the coil, and then bringing a 50 Ohm cable to the signal generator.

Comment: How big is the coil? If it's 6 turns, and more than 50 mm diameter, then you have an antenna, and the usual equations won't work.

Comment: When I measure U(coil), I'm connecting o-scope directly to the coil. It still gives me different Reactance(coil) when I use different resistors.

Comment: I need to connect this 6-round coil with 6-meter wire. The coil cannot be connected directly to signal generator. It's 6 turn, 15mm diameter, 1~2mm copper wire diameter.

Comment: Can you show a circuit diagram of the whole measurement system? Show the scope, including ground leads, the signal generator, the resistor and the coil itself. Use the built-in circuit editor to add it to your question. Are the resistors really non-inductive? I recommend using 0805 smd resistors for this.

Comment: If you can post the diagram tomnexus asked for, please pay particular attention to describing that 6 meter long "wire". Also, what's the length of the coil and how is it connected to the wire?

Comment: The only sensible way is to put the two matching capacitors (and balun) at the coil, and use a 50 Ohm cable. For the coil Z measurement, clip the scope directly onto the resistor+coil. Later, extend the 50 Ohm cable as far as necessary. I've done this exact measurement at 900MHz with a siggen+scope+resistor, to find complex impedance of an IC, it agreed well with the VNA.

Comment: I add the picture. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score -1):

1) If you have an inductive load with an impedance you're trying to match you can't do it with just a resistor.

2a) You can't treat an inductive reactance as if it were a pure resistance because the voltage across it and the current through it won't be in phase.

2b) You can't treat an inductance in series with a resistance as if the reactance was a resistance because the voltages across the inductance and the resistance won't be in phase.

3) $$ Xl = \sqrt {Z^2 - R^2} $$

Comment: I'm putting a test resistor in series with coil + wire, to measure the reactance of coil. U(resistor) / U(coil) = R(resistor) / Impedance(coil). Impedance(coil) = Reactance(coil), because Resistance(coil) is 0 ohms.

Comment: I'm trying to learn from your answer. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Sean: Sorry about that, but if you can't be bothered to provide the information I asked for, I fail to see why your inability to understand my answer is my responsibility.